# Subsetting dataframe by day according to most non zero data

Tags: r

I have an example dataframe:

```
a <- c(1:6)
b <- c("05/12/2012 05:00","05/12/2012 06:00","06/12/2012 05:00",
   "06/12/2012 06:00", "07/12/2012 09:00","07/12/2012 07:00")
c <-c("0","0","0","1","1","1")
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Firstly, I want to make sure R recognises the date and time format, so I used:

```
df1$b <- strptime(df1$b, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

However this can't be right as R always aborts my session as soon as I try to view the new dataframe.

Assuming that this gets resolves, I want to get a subset of the data according to whichever day in the dataframe contains the most data in 'C' that is not a zero.  In the above example I should be left with the two data points on 7th Dec 2012.

I also have an additional, related question.
If I want to be left with a subset of the data with the most non zero values between a certain time period in the day (say between 07:00 and 08:00), how would I go about doing this?

Any help on the above problems would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "However this can't be right as R always aborts my session as soon as I try to view the new dataframe." I was unable to reproduce any kind of crash by creating and manipulating `df1` via the code in your question (R version 2.15.2 on OSX Mountain Lion).

Comment: "If I want to be left with a subset of the data with the most non zero values between a certain time period..."  Could you clarify?  Do you mean all the non-zero values or are you comparing days?

Comment: Many thanks @Dinre - I mean subsetting a day (out of 7) with the most non zero values between a set time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the good news is that I have an answer for you, and the bad news is that you have more questions to ask yourself.  First the bad news: you need to consider how you want to treat multiple days that have the same number of non-zero values for 'c'.  I'm not going to address that in this answer.

Now the good news: this is really simple.

**Step 1**: First, let's reformat your data frame.  Since we're changing data types on a couple of the variables (b to datetime and c to numeric), we need to create a new data frame or recalibrate the old one.  I prefer to preserve the original and create a new one, like so:

```
a <- df1$a
b <- strptime(df1$b, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
c <- as.numeric(df1$c)
hour <- as.numeric(format(b, "%H"))
date <- format(b, "%x")

df2 <- data.frame(a, b, c, hour, date)

#   a                   b c hour      date
# 1 1 2012-12-05 05:00:00 0    5 12/5/2012
# 2 2 2012-12-05 06:00:00 0    6 12/5/2012
# 3 3 2012-12-06 05:00:00 0    5 12/6/2012
# 4 4 2012-12-06 06:00:00 1    6 12/6/2012
# 5 5 2012-12-07 09:00:00 1    9 12/7/2012
# 6 6 2012-12-07 07:00:00 1    7 12/7/2012
```

Notice that I also added 'hour' and 'date' variables.  This is to make our data easily sortable by those fields for our later aggregation function.

**Step 2**: Now, let's calculate how many non-zero values there are for each day between the hours of 06:00 and 08:00.  Since we're using the 'hour' values, this means the values of '6' and '7' (represents 06:00 - 07:59).

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df2[df2$hour %in% 6:7,], .(date), mutate, non_zero=sum(c))

#   a                   b c hour      date non_zero
# 1 2 2012-12-05 06:00:00 0    6 12/5/2012        0
# 2 4 2012-12-06 06:00:00 1    6 12/6/2012        1
# 3 6 2012-12-07 07:00:00 1    7 12/7/2012        1
```

The 'plyr' package is wonderful for things like this.  The 'ddply' package specifically takes data frames as both input and output (hence the "dd"), and the 'mutate' function allows us to preserve all the data while adding additional columns.  In this case, we're wanting a sum of 'c' for each day in `.(date)`.  Subsetting our data by the hours is taken care of in the data argument `df2[df2$hour %in% 6:7,]`, which says to show us the rows where the hour value is in the set {6,7}.

**Step 3**: The final step is just to subset the data by the max number of non-zero values.  We can drop the extra columns we used and go back to our original three.

```
subset_df <- df2[df2$non_zero==max(df2$non_zero),1:3]

#   a                   b c
# 2 4 2012-12-06 06:00:00 1
# 3 6 2012-12-07 07:00:00 1
```

Good luck!

**Update**: At the OP's request, I am writing a new 'ddply' function that will also include a time column for plotting.

```
df2 <- ddply(df2[df2$hour %in% 6:7,], .(date), mutate, non_zero=sum(c), plot_time=as.numeric(format(b, "%H")) + as.numeric(format(b, "%M")) / 60)
subset_df <- df2[df2$non_zero==max(df2$non_zero),c("a","b","c","plot_time")]
```

We need to collapse the time down into one continuous variable, so I chose hours.  Leaving any data in a time format will require us to fiddle with stuff later, and using a string format (like "hh:mm") will limit the types of functions you can use on it.  Continuous numbers are the most flexible, so here we get the number of hours `as.numeric(format(b, "%H"))` and add it to the number of minutes divided by 60 `as.numeric(format(b, "%M")) / 60` to convert the minutes into units of hours.  Also, since we're dealing with more columns, I've switched the final subset statement to name the columns we want, rather than referring to the numbers.  Once I'm dealing with columns that aren't in continuous order, I find that using names is easier to debug.

Comment: This looks perfect @Dinre, but there must be something weird with my real data (it works when I follow your steps on the dummy data)as when I strptime by my 'b' variable and then produce my new dataframe, I get a very random long number (e.g. 1354683600 instead of 2012-12-05 05:00:00).  Do you know how I get back to the proper date?

Comment: I also wish to be left with a column that just includes the time (as this will then be graphed).  Why does the following code not work (using your example data)? time <- as.numeric(format(b, "%H:%M")) Many thanks @Dinre.

Comment: The result of `format(b, "%H:%M")` cannot be coerced into a number, because the '%H' and '%M' are different units and the ':' is not a recognized separation character for numbers.  You have to do the conversion manually by breaking the numbers apart, converting into similar units, and then adding.  There may be another way, but this is the one I find most reliable.

Comment: Many thanks @Dinre - your help is very much appreciated.  I was just trying to understand your original code.  In step 3 subset the data by the max number of non-zero values.  I want to be left with one day's worth of data with the most non-zeros (not two days as listed in the final dataframe of Stage 3).  What's the best code for this?

Comment: I mentioned this in the top of the answer.  The problem is that you haven't defined what you want to happen when multiple days have the same max number of non-zero values.  This code pulls all the days that match the maximum, which will be one or more.  It's up to you how you want to address this.  What do you want to do?

Comment: Apologies @Dinre.  This shouldn't be too much of a problem on my real data as I have data every 2 minutes (and for starters I am looking at a much wider window of time - 5 am to 11 pm).  But if it is the same, perhaps it could choose the day with the highest numbers?

Comment: That will still leave you with the possibility that those days have the same numbers.  To be fully exclusive, you would need to pick a non-random point to use as a perfect tie-break.  For instance, in case of a tie, you could always pick the earliest date with something like `subset_df[1,]` or pick the latest date with `subset_df[nrow(subset_df),]`.  This is equivalent to the 'FIRST' and 'LAST' methods in SQL that are frequently use for arbitrary tie-breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing with Jack. Sounds like a corrupted installation of R. First thing to try would be to delete the `.Rdata` file that holds the results of the prior session. They are hidden in both Mac and Windows so unless you "reveal" the 'dotfiles'(system files), the OS file manager (Finder.app and Windows Explorer) will not show them. How you find and delete that file is OS-specific task. It's going to be in your working directory and you will need to do the deletion outside of R since once R is started it will have locked access to it. It's also possible to get a corrupt `.history` file but in my experience that is not usually the source of the problem.

If that is not successful, you may need to reinstall R.

Comment: I have reproduced the error on a Windows machine, the bug report is filed [here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/4931-view-crashes-rstudio-on-windows-7).