# Hour and minutes in one column in R

Tags: r

I have a simple dataframe.  From which I want to add another column that records the time (hours and minutes, in the 24 hour clock).  I am then going to graph this column against a variable.  As the dates are all the same, I am only interested in the time. This is what I have tried so far.

```
a <- c(1:6)
b <- c("05/12/2012 05:00","05/12/2012 06:55","05/12/2012 07:10",
       "05/12/2012 10:23", "05/12/2012 11:43","05/12/2012 13:04")
c <-c("0","0","0","1","1","1")
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

a <- df1$a
b <- strptime(df1$b, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
c <- as.numeric(df1$c)
hour <- as.numeric(format(b, "%H"))
min <- as.numeric(format(b, "%M"))
date <- format(b, "%x")
time <- hour + min

df2 <- data.frame(a, b, c, hour, min, date, time)
```

I was advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735689/subsetting-dataframe-by-day-according-to-most-non-zero-data) to convert the mins and hours manually by breaking the numbers apart, converting into similar units, and then adding. However I am struggling as 5 am simply gets imported as 5.

If anyone could advise me how I might do this properly, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being dense, but what *should* 5 be imported as if its not 5? Maybe you're wanting to multiply your hours by 60 or divide minutes by 60?  Or just plot the dates so you don't have to deal!

Comment: Many thanks @Justin.  I want the first time to be either 05:00 or 0500 whichever is the simplist to compute.

Comment: You should use `paste(hour, min, sep=':')` rather than `+`.  There you're just adding two numbers that have no knowledge of time.  But, instead, I would suggest using a timestamp data type (`?as.POSIXct`) to avoid all this potential confusion.

Comment: As the person who recommended the above method, the time was getting converted into a single unit of hours, so '05:00' would be '5' and '05:30' would be '5.5' using code like `as.numeric(format(time, "%H")) + as.numeric(format(time, "%M"))`.  This was done originally to allow the plotting of time data from multiple dates to be placed along the same 0:24 axis.  Perhaps the OP can clarify what the problem is and how the output is intended to be used, so we can fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are numerous conversion tools for dates and times, and a whole set of packages to use. I like working with `POSIXlt` in this case, as you can extract whatever info you need simply by extracting them from the list.

eg:

```
a <- c(1:6)
b <- c("05/12/2012 05:00","05/12/2012 06:55","05/12/2012 07:10",
       "05/12/2012 10:23", "05/12/2012 11:43","05/12/2012 13:04")
c <-c("0","0","0","1","1","1")
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- within(df1,{
  posb <- as.POSIXlt(b,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
  hours <- posb$hour
  mins <- posb$min
  dates <- format(posb, "%x")
  time <- format(posb, "%H:%M")
  posb <- NULL  # cleanup
})
```

Which gives :

```
> df2
  a                b c  time     dates mins hours
1 1 05/12/2012 05:00 0 05:00 12/5/2012    0     5
2 2 05/12/2012 06:55 0 06:55 12/5/2012   55     6
3 3 05/12/2012 07:10 0 07:10 12/5/2012   10     7
4 4 05/12/2012 10:23 1 10:23 12/5/2012   23    10
5 5 05/12/2012 11:43 1 11:43 12/5/2012   43    11
6 6 05/12/2012 13:04 1 13:04 12/5/2012    4    13
```

For more information, see also :

- `?POSIXlt` for more info on the POSIXt classes
- `?format` for more info on formatting options
- `?strptime` for more info on formatting options and conversion to character
- the [`lubridate` package](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i03/paper) for alternative functions
- the [`timeDate` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/) for yet more alternative functions
- ...

Comment: On a sidenote, you might want to learn to use the `within` function for readibility of your code. Pretty powerful thingy.