# R Studio aborting with time series data

Tags: r

I am having trouble working with some time series data in R.

```
a <- c(1:6)
b <- c("05/12/2012 05:00","05/12/2012 06:00","06/12/2012 05:00",
       "06/12/2012 06:00", "07/12/2012 09:00","07/12/2012 07:00")
c <-c("0","0","0","1","1","1")
df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$b <- strptime(df1$b, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

I am using R Studio (version 0.97.314).  When I run the last line of code, converting b to a date variable and then try to view this dataframe in the workspace window, R Studio aborts.

I reported this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735689/subsetting-dataframe-by-day-according-to-most-non-zero-data) and was advised it was a corrupted version of R.  However, I ran the same code on another windows pc and I had the same problem.  I also emailed the support at R Studio and they advised me that the session was aborting because of the R code I was using.  I have reinstalled both R and R studio (and updated to the most recent versin of R Studio) and still had the same problem.  Can anyone advise of any other solutions?

When I try to work with my real data, I get a slightly different problem.  When I run the code to format the date correctly, my date column has ben transformed to lots of zeros.  The other eight rows are just lists of numbers.  When I use dput() to output the first four rows of my dataframe, I get this:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(40L, 
42L, 44L, 46L), hour = c(18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), mday = c(14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L), mon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), year = c(112L, 112L, 
112L, 112L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), yday = c(348L, 348L, 348L, 
348L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", 
"mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), LATITUDE = c(54.77769505, 54.77700313, 54.77770803, 
54.77830731), LONGITUDE = c(-1.56627049, -1.57128976, -1.57544758, 
-1.58108564), HEIGHT = c(" 173.911 M", " 94.833 M", " 137.995 M", 
" 101.871 M"), SPEED = c(" 0.465 km/h", " 10.164 km/h", " 9.129 km/h", 
" 6.340 km/h")), .Names = c("Date", "LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE", 
"HEIGHT", "SPEED"), row.names = c(1L, 13L, 25L, 37L), class = "data.frame")
```

The only reason I wish to ensure the dates are correctly formatted, is because I wish to get rid of obervations which are after a certain point in time, using the code:

```
gps <- subset(gps, Date > strptime("14/12/2012 19:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
```

I had previously formatted the local time and date columns using:

```
gps <- transform(gps, Date=format(as.POSIXct(paste(LOCAL.DATE, LOCAL.TIME)), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"))
```

However I get the error message:

Error in Date > strptime("14/12/2012 19:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") : 
  comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "Ops.POSIXt") for ">"
2: In Date > strptime("14/12/2012 19:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Many thanks.

Comment: Please, if you have an addition to an existing question, edit that question to add more details. In addition, if you post a new question, indicate exactly what you did with the answers you already got, and why they where not sufficient.

Comment: The reason I posted a new question was that the previous question which actually involved subsetting dataframe most non zero data was answered perfectly.  I did make a fly away comment in my original question that my R session aborted so this stack overflow question concerned this primarily.  As I said in my text, I reinstalled both R and R studio and am still having the same problems.  If you want me to add these details to the other question, I am happy to.

Comment: This is not reproducible, i.e. it works for me on RStudio 0.97.316

Comment: Works well here too, with RStudio 0.97.312 under linux.

Comment: I can reproduce the "data view" error on R version 2.15.2 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with RStudio 0.97.316. I'll make a proper bug report.

Comment: The [bug report is here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/4931-view-crashes-rstudio-on-windows-7). But note that you could just type `df1` if all you wanted to do was view it.

Comment: FYI - The problem was with R Studio - R itself when run separately produces no errors.